# Use variable inside for each loop in Meter

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I have two variables `group1` and `group2_list` in Meteor. I need to do this:

```
{{#each group2_list}}
<p><a href="{{pathFor 'page_detail' group1=group1._id group2=_id}}">{{_id}}</a></p>
{{/each}}
```

but `group1._id` is not available.

I can use `group1._id` outside `{{#each group2_list}}...{{/each}}` but I guess it thinks `group1._id` is a field in object in group2_list. How can I use `group1._id` as a normal variable and not as a variable inside objects from group2_list?

## edit

The variables are populated through the router

```
data: function() {
  return {
    'group1': Group1.findOne(this.params._id),
    'group2_list': Group2.find({group1Id: this.params._id}),
  }
},
```

Comment: is it possible for you to share where group1_list is declared and ended ? I suspect, you close group1_list and then you are trying to use it.

Comment: is this expression correct? **{{pathFor 'page_detail' group1=group1._id group2=_id}}**

Comment: Please show us more of your router code, especially `page_detail`. And `{{pathFor}}` only accepts `route`, `data`, `query`, and `hash` as arguments: https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#pathfor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access template level variables within the `#each` loop just add `../` in front of the variable name. Think of it as the relative path to the variable. If you want to go up one level use `../` or `../../` if you want to go up two levels.

```
{{#each group2_list}}
    <p><a href="{{pathFor 'page_detail' group1=../group1._id group2=_id}}">{{_id}}</a></p>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. But it looks a bit like a hack. Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: They have examples of this method in the meteor documentation, so I assume it's standard practice. It's just not well documented.